# Zf2 Disable layout application wide

Tags: zend-framework2

Currently I am trying to build an application with Zend Framework 2 that incorporates modal screens through an ajax request. My plan was to disable the layout when modal is specified as a URL parameter. However if I try the code below, I get the following error:

```
Zend\View\Exception\DomainException:
Inconsistent state; child view model is marked as terminal
```

With this code:

```
$events->attach ( MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, function ( MvcEvent $e ) use ($sm) {
    if ($e->getRequest()->getQuery('modal') !== null) {
        $result = $e->getResult();
        if ($result instanceof ViewModel) {
            $result->setTerminal(true);
        }
    }
}, -100);
```

Can somebody tell me how to do this, or tell me what is wrong with this code?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you the view script too ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming at. All view scripts are in place and they work properly if ?modal is not specified. However, when ?modal is set and the code above is executed then `Zend\View\Exception\DomainException: Inconsistent state; child view model is marked as terminal` is the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer has been found in another forum:

```
$sharedEvents = $app->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
$sharedEvents->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController','dispatch', function($e) {
    $result = $e->getResult();
    $request = $e->getApplication()->getRequest();
    if ($result instanceof ViewModel && $request->getQuery('modal') !== null) {
       $result->setTerminal(true);
    }
});
```

From this forum topic: [Zend Framework Contributor](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Disable-layout-with-Query-parameter-td4659897.html#a4659902)